# Send email to all users of a role except certain users?

Tags: 7, views, rules

I'd like to send an email to a users of a certain role.
I've already did it with Rules module, but now I want to expand my rule and send email to only certain role's but to a specific users of that role.

Example:
`Send email to a role admin, except user with name or email (test/test@test.com)`

Is it possible to do it via Rules module or maybe some custom executable PHP code?

Thanks in Michael.

Comment: This can be done with Rule. You probably need to add a exclude and add the role that you want too.

Comment: @darol100 i've checked both D7 and D6 for any exclude rule option. Can you clarify ? Thanks!

Comment: no. no action. and i fixed it on Drupal7 with view_rules module, but now im working on Drupal6 and its giving me a headache :/